# How to correctly pass a copy of pandas list_of_dataframes to a function?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, function

1. I have a list of dataframes -

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

2. Pass its copy to a function -

```
def fun(df_l):
   # code to stop ww3 using the copy of df_l

fun(df_list.copy())
```

Now, this is in relation to a bigger issue that i am trying to deal with since a day and a half already, but for the sake of this question, following is exactly what i want to confirm.

Expectation is for `df_l` to have `[df1.copy(), df2.copy(), df3.copy()]`
Is this expectation right?

I am unsure if _is_copy() can help here.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: No. Nothing in the line `df_list.copy()` tells python to call the `.copy` method of every element in `df_list`. If anything, you should copy the dataframes, not the list. Try `fun(map(lambda df: df.copy(), df_list))`.

Comment: Or just ask about your *actual* problem. As you stated yourself, as of now this is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @DeepSpace Your answer with lamda resolves my issue. Please add it as your answer instead of comment so i can accept it. If not i can do the same referencing to your comment. BTW, the actual problem was the annoying "SettingWithCopy" warnings. I did not post the original because it was very wound-up and even irrelevant. (EDIT: I ll wait for till tomorrow before i post it myself.)

Comment: `SettingWithCopy` warning is a totally different problem. It's well stated in the documentations, as well as many questions on SO.